# How do I use .htaccess to limit file uploads to .pdf?

Tags: .htaccess, dns, file-structure

I have a simple upload form that allows a file to be uploaded to a folder in the site.  I don't want to allow anything but .pdf files to be uploaded.  However, I cannot modify the form at all to limit the upload. And I can't use PHP on the back end to limit it either. Javascript is unsecure because a user can turn it off. How can I limit the upload to a .pdf file with .htaccess?

Comment: javascript not being "secure" is the least of your worries…

Comment: … hu? hop, please explain yourself.

Comment: if the backend code is not php, what is it?

Comment: @David: there is no way to make pdf itself secure or to even reliably filter out pdfs that contain malicious code, videos, data, whatever… assuming you meant "explain your statement," not "explain yourself."

Comment: Ah, sure, fair enough. However, that doesn't seem very helpful, as it's entirely orthogonal to the question.

Comment: @David: hence is commented instead of answering. also, there isn't really an answerable question there, imho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, it isn't possible. You could, however, restrict the files being *returned*, and force their mime type to be `application/pdf`, so they will be treated like PDFs, even if they aren't. If this was combined with JavaScript, it would help honest users (ex, if someone accidentally selects a `.jpg` they will get a warning right away), and it will make attacks more difficult.

It seems like the third-party [mod_upload](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_upload/) might be able to help, though.

To restrict the output types, you could use a `.htaccess` file similar to this:

```
# Prevent request to non-.pdf files
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! \.pdf$
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [F]
# Tell the browser that this is a PDF
Header set Content-Type application/pdf
# Hint that the browser shouldn't try to auto-detect the content type
Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
```

(note: I wrote those from memory, so make sure to test them before you trust them…)

Comment: sounds like an option.  How would I restrict returned files with .htaccess?